# How do I get the output of Win32::Process command in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl

I am using `use Win32::Process` for my application run as below. It runs fine, but I did not get any way to get the output to a .txt file.

I used NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS rather than CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE to get the output on the same terminal itself, but I don't know how to redirect it to a txt file.

/rocky

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::Process;

Win32::Process::Create(my $ProcessObj,
                       "iperf.exe",
                       "iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001",
                       0,
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       ".") || die ErrorReport();
my @command_output;

push @command_output,$ProcessObj;

open FILE, ">zz.txt" or die $!;
print FILE @command_output;
close FILE;

sleep 10;
$ProcessObj->Kill(0);

sub ErrorReport{
    print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Win32::Process is one of those modules that's basically a straight port of the Win32 API into Perl and thus makes little sense to a Perl programmer.  Unless you want to do something very Windows specific, there are better ways to do it.

If all you want is to get the output of a process, you can just run it normally using Perl's backticks.

```
my $output = `iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001`;
```

If you want to get fancy, for example backgrounding a process and capturing its output, I'd recommend [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.89/lib/IPC/Run.pm#run()_vs._start();_pump();_finish();).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Win32::Process by redirecting STDOUT and STDERR to a text file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Which qw(which);
use Win32;
use Win32::Process;

# Back up STDOUT and STDERR to OLDOUT and OLDERR
open (OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT");
open (OLDERR, ">&STDERR");

# Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to text file
my $file = "output.txt";
open (STDOUT, ">$file");
open (STDERR, ">&STDOUT");

# Create process
my $timeout = 60000 * 10; # 10 minute timeout
my ($process, $exitCode);
my $exe = which 'iperf';
Win32::Process::Create($process, $exe, "iperf.exe -u -s -p 5001", 1, 0, ".");
$process->Wait($timeout);
$process->GetExitCode($exitCode);
print "Spawned process exited with $exitCode\n";

# Restore STDOUT and STDERR
close (STDOUT);
close (STDERR);
open (STDOUT, ">&OLDOUT");
open (STDERR, ">&OLDERR");
close (OLDOUT);
close (OLDERR);
```

Note that in the Win32::Process::Create call, it is important to set $iflags and $cflags correctly (as in the example above) to ensure that the spawned process inherits the calling processes handles/console. The meanings of these flags can be found in the Win32::Process and Microsoft Windows documentation:

[Win32::Process CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Process-0.16/Process.pm)

[Microsoft Windows process creation flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html):

> Backticks (``) run a command and return what it sent to STDOUT.

More details can be found in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).